# How to change the name of an entry?

Tags: entry, singles

I'm new with CMS and I'm not able to change the name of an entry (single).
How could I do that?
Thanks in advance!
Vincent

Answer (score 4):

`Settings > Sections > [Open your Page] > Change Name > Save`

Answer (score 1):

JMKelley has the right answer - adding that if you have a use case where an author needs to change the text, then be sure to make a field to use instead for display purposes. For singles its common practise for the title to just be a CMS title (rather than the text for a menu item or hero). Cheers!